# Getting a 403 Forbidden error when attempting to publish to GCP from a Spring Boot application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I am attempting to utilize PubSub in my Spring Boot application to send messages to another service any time an item is updated or created. I have been simply trying to test the functionality of publishing a test message before setting it up for what I will actually need it for. However I am having some difficulty linking my application up to GCP. Every time I attempt to publish I receive a 403 Forbidden error as seen below.

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/sa-test-app@test-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This error comes through about 10 minutes after I attempt the publish, when the request times out. I have tried this out using a service account and topic from my colleague's project that has been able to successfully publish and subscribe to GCP PubSub but I still receive the same error.

My code is nearly identical to my colleague's project with my publishing present in my @RestController as such:

```java
@Autowired
    PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;
    @GetMapping("/postMessage")
    public String publish(@RequestParam("topicName") String topicName,
                          @RequestParam("message") String message) {
        pubSubTemplate.publish(topicName, message);


        return "Messages published asynchronously; status unknown.";
    }
```

And my subscription code in it's own PubSubConfig file as such:

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class PubSubConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubSubInputChannel() { return new PublishSubscribeChannel(); }

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("pubSubInputChannel") MessageChannel inputChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
                new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, "test_pullsub");
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        adapter.setPayloadType(String.class);
        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubSubInputChannel")
    public void messageReceiver(String payload,
                                @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE) BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message) {
        log.info("Message arrived via an inbound channel adapter from sub-one! Payload: " + payload);
        message.ack();
    }
}
```

I am triggering the publish event by sending a get request in Postman to the URL `http://localhost:8080/cloc/postMessage?topicName=test-topic&message=Hello` with the application running locally.

I am able to reach a breakpoint set at `pubSubTemplate.publish(topicName, message);` but after that the message is unable to go through.

I have been able to successfully publish a message via the Google CLI using the command
`gcloud pubsub topics publish test-topic --message="Hello World"`
So I don't believe it is a permission issue with the service account.

If needed the imports I am using in my `build.gradle` file are as such:

```java
bomImport platform('io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:2.4.1')
bomImport platform (group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies', version: '3.2.1')
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:1.2.5.RELEASE'
implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.10.0')
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken`.

Add the IAM `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` (Service Account Token Creator) to the service account receiving this error.

[Roles for managing and impersonating service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions)

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to modify the permissions on the service account, only specific admins have that capability. The permissions present on my service account that is having issues are [here](https://paste.pics/eaddd61db85d5b51ffdc69a300a6f001). The permissions on the service account that has no issues are [here](https://paste.pics/5179e02d5e631fe2d4a4a01047e0c73f). Which of these permissions are needed to get past the 403 error I am receiving?

Comment: I was able to impersonate another service account that was created with similar permissions to the service account that was working fine. With the new service account that has all of the proper permissions I was able to both publish and subscribe to my topic.

Comment: @scottyboombox - You need to ask one of the admins to grant you permission. There is no shortcut around that requirement. Note: Your second image contains "custom" roles. You will need to review which permissions were attached to those roles. I cannot from a screnshot.

Comment: @scottyboombox - If you are able to impersonate another service account, then your admins have not done their job correctly. Backdoors happen when security is not implemented correctly.